# iOSでCoreMotionのデバイス姿勢取得より早い、姿勢取得方法が知りたい（VR用）

Tags: swift, ios, unity3d

#### 前提・実現したいこと

iOSでCoreMotionのデバイス姿勢取得より早い取得方法が知りたいです。
どんな些細な疑問やヒントでも助かります。。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

https://github.com/googlevr/cardboard
こちらのSDKでVRアプリを開発しているのですが
YoutubeのVRと比べると、回転の取得が遅く（0.01~2秒程度）、VR酔いが激しいです。
そこでYoutuveVR並みの回転取得速度を目指したいのですが、アプローチの仕方がわかりませんので
なにかヒントでもいいのでご教授いただけないかと相談させていただきました。

#### 試したこと

SDKを使用せずにCoreMotionから直接姿勢の値を取得
→ほんの少しだけ早くなりました。

#### 補足情報

iOS14
Unity2019.4

最終的にはUnityで開発したいのですが、まずはSwiftでそれを実現できればと思っております。
私がUnityエンジニアでSwiftに疎いので、ご容赦頂ければ幸いです。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 基本的には、Unityで作るよりもSwiftネイティブで作る方が速度が上がると思います。コードのサンプルがないと何とも言えないのですが、何秒に１度データを取得するか(サンプリング時間)を変えるなどするのも問題の解決に繋がる可能性はあります。また、CoreMotionの速度が遅いというより、Swiftのコード自体に速度が遅くなる原因がある可能性もあります。

Comment: gncc 様
ありがとうございます。
サンプリング時間など、調べてみます！
また困ったとき助けていただけると幸いです。